# Balancing AVL tree

Tags: c++, tree, avl-tree

I have tried to implement AVL tree.

I created node

```
struct node{
    int key;
    int height;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node( int k ){
        key = k;
        left = right = nullptr;
        height = 1;
    }
    node ( int k , int h ){
        key = k;
        left = right = nullptr;
        height = h;
    }
};
```

function to calculate / set height

```
int height( node *p){
    return p ? p -> height : 0;
}


int bfactor( node *p ){
    return height( p -> right ) - height( p -> left );
}

void fixheight( node *p ){
    unsigned char hl = height( p -> left );
    unsigned char hr = height( p -> right);
    p -> height = ( hl > hr ? hl : hr ) + 1;
}
```

left and right balance

```
node* rotateright(node* p)
{
    node* q = p->left;
    p->left = q->right;
    q->right = p;
    fixheight(p);
    fixheight(q);
    return q;
}

node* rotateleft(node* q)
{
    node* p = q->right;
    q->right = p->left;
    p->left = q;
    fixheight(q);
    fixheight(p);
    return p;
}
```

total balance - if i insert values right into tree , the difference between heights can be either 2 or - 2. 2 if right tree is higher -2 if left.

```
node* balance(node* p){
    fixheight(p);
    if( bfactor(p)==2 )
    {
        if( bfactor(p->right) < 0 )
            p->right = rotateright(p->right);
        return rotateleft(p);
    }
    if( bfactor(p)==-2 )
    {
        if( bfactor(p->left) > 0  )
            p->left = rotateleft(p->left);
        return rotateright(p);
    }
    return p; // balancing is not required
}
```

and simple insert

```
node* insert(node* p, int k)
{
    if( !p ) {
            return new node(k);
    }
    if( k<p->key )
        p->left = insert(p->left,k);
    else
        p->right = insert(p->right,k);
    return balance(p);
}
```

What troubles me is when i test it. Lets asume i insert , 5 , 6 , 7 , 1 , the tree should looks like

```
     5
    / \
   1   6
        \
         7
```

Which is balaned tree , the height of does not differ by number greater than 1.
Yet the balance function gets invoked on the 2 case.

I writed the it down and it should not happen , i am new to using c++ and such langauges i tried using debuger but it didnt help me . Could anybody hint me whats cause this unwanted behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: After inserting `5,6,7` in that sequence, the root should become `6`, not `5`. So when you insert `1`, the tree would look different, not what you think it should look like (as shown in your question).

Comment: Ah yes now i see it! Thanks!